# AngularUI: Correctly updating the models between two lists with a filter applied

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Sortable within AngularUI to manage multiple sortable lists. I've got it working to the point where I can easily move items between the lists, and update their corresponding models accordingly. However, if I include a query filter I run into a bit of issues if the following takes place:

1. The user enters a search field for an item that is NOT the first entry of a list.
2. The user moves the first item in the filtered results from one list to another.
3. It seems to work, until the query is cleared and the initial lists are shown. While it seemed that you moved the entry when you had the query applied, you'll notice that after it's cleared the first entry in the unfiltered array was moved instead.

It seems that Sortable doesn't take filters into account when you are dragging and dropping. Here's the relevant HTML:

```
  <p>Search: <input ng-model="query" /></p>
  <div class="column-wrapper">
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableTemplates" ng-model="list1" id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list1|filter:query" class="itemBox">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul ui-sortable="sortableTemplates" ng-model="list2" id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li ng-repeat="item in list2|filter:query" class="itemBox">{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And the corresponding JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.sortable']);
app.controller('test', function($scope) {

$scope.list1 = [
    {name: 'ABC'},
    {name: 'DEF'},
    {name: 'GHI'}
];

$scope.list2 = [
    {name: 'JKL'},
    {name: 'MNO'},
    {name: 'QRS'}
];

$scope.sortableTemplates = {
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
}
```

});

[Here it is running on Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/1WhMLrBwaxK4t8pnThj3?p=preview)

To replicate the problem, you can try doing a search for `GHI`, then moving `GHI` to list2. Then, clear the search box. `ABC` is the one that actually  moves to list2 (as it is the first element in that array), and `GHI` remains in list one.

Is there a way to have sortable get along with Angular filters, so that the original index is preserved when sorting between lists?

(I'm new to using Angular as well as JQueryUI, so the answer may be glaringly obvious. I found similar questions, but nothing that seemed to directly address this issue.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say ui-sortable is using the elements index to move it between the lists, so that when you move the first item in your filtered list it moves the first item in your original list.
One way around this is instead of filtering your lists is to hide the items you don't want to be able to move, rather than creating a new list as the filter in your ng-repeat does.
so in your html:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list1" class="itemBox" ng-show="visible(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
```

ng-show will show or hide the element depending upon whether $scope.visible(item) returns true or false. 
We therefore create a function in our controller which returns true if we want to see the element, i.e. it is not filtered out, and false if it is filtered out.

```
$scope.visible=function(item){
  //create an array containing all of the elements in both lists
  var lists=$scope.list1.concat($scope.list2);
  // filter this list using our search term
  var filteredItems=$filter('filter')(lists, $scope.query);
  //if there are no matching items left in our list then return false
  if (filteredItems.length===0){return false;}
  //see if the current item is in the filtered list   
  if (($filter('filter')(filteredItems,item)).length===1){
     return true;
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

I have created a plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/JCQdcP?p=preview

Comment: Hey, i was wondering if you know a way to make your answer fast like the ng-repeat filter is? i have a list of a couple hundred. The visible function brings the webpage to a halt when the search box is typed in. It worked great on local dev, but with real data it was rough. Any ideas?

Comment: @j_walker_dev - I'm curious about this as well. I've got it running with this method which is fine for the most part, but it does slow to a crawl if there's too many elements to search. I haven't had time to really delve into finding an alternative yet though.

Comment: I never found a good one. I implemented a _.debounce from lodash to make the typing appear faster, when really its just not searching as much. If you want some code for that, let me know.

Comment: Hiding is the perfect solution here. It enables reordering while filtered.